# Environmental variable in package.json file dependency

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to include environmental variables in the package.json under the dependencies area? Or is NPM not capable of this?

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0",
    "ver": "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_PERSONAL_TOKEN}@example.com:pr/ver.git#0.1.0",
    "squel": "^5.11.1"
  }
```

Comment: I think there is no way how to do hits by default. But you can always have some script, that first process i.e. file `_package.json`, exchange the `${}` variables with environmental variable values, save it as package.json and then starts the npm install

Comment: @libik Exactly what I'm doing atm, however this doesn't work when your private repo's themselves require other private repos.